# EXCEPTION: Root segment cannot have matrix parameters

Tags: angular

**Html:**

```
[routerLink]="['', {'scrollTo': '#contact'}]"
```

**TS:**

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    if (params['scrollTo']) {
        // some code here
    }
});
```

Error: EXCEPTION: Root segment cannot have matrix parameters

I can't have 'scrollTo' param in my routerLink?

It clearly appears on the angular 2 documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#appendix-link-parameters-array

**EDIT:**

Doesn't seem to complaint with : `<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', { scrollTo: '#contact' }]">Crisis Center</a>`. But I need it with my '' root route.

Comment: I also got this `Root segment` error but it in my case it wasn't caused by `params` in the `routerLink` array. Instead i had accidentally included an `object` variable instead of a plain `string` as a path segment in the array. When this object is then stringified angular probably mistakes it for a set of matrix parameters which then causes the same error to be thrown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recently, it is done this way in Angular 5+:

`<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{ 'tour': true }"> text </a>`

Doing `[routerLink]="['/', { 'tour': true' }]"> text </a>` would throw the error

Comment: Heaven forbid any part of the framework makes it for more than 2 versions with no breaking changes.

Comment: @user3640967 Welcome to the Angular Club. Breaking changes is served for breakfast here!

Comment: The first option would use query params, while the second option would use matrix params. They are not the same.

Comment: @JWess you're absolutely right, I added an answer specifically for matrix params - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59990597/228369

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is wrong, it sets query params (e.g ?myparam=true). To set matrix parameters (e.g ;myparam=15;foo=foo) the syntax is:

```
[routerLink]="['.', {'scrollTo': '#contact'}]"
```

Notice the period in the route. As is explained here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9505

That's how to set matrix parameters, and it fails with "''" because that's for the root route, which apparently won't allow matrix parameters-

Comment: apparently! so we are doomed, no matrix on root :(

Answer (score 2):

The root segment cannot have matrix params. There are two reasons for this:

- There is no place in the URL to put them.
- Currently we reuse components when their parameters change, but in the future we will
  provide a way to customize the reuse behavior. So the developer will
  be able to get a new copy of a component any time its args change.
  Since the root component is created statically, we cannot implement
  it for the root component.

Comment: The root segment has query params instead of matrix. Matrix is only for child routes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but what does that mean? how to i set query params?

Comment: AFAIK query params are set the same as matrix params, they are just serialized differently. For the root segment they are serialized as query parameters `/root/child1/child2?name=value&name2=value` while for other segments they are serialized as matrix parameters `/root/child1;name=value;name2=value/child2`. I guess if you have empty paths in parent and child route, the router might just not know where to apply the params.

Comment: @titusfx not sure what your question is about. A route consisting of several segments (routes and child routes) each segment can have its own parameters. Only one can use the query parameters, because there is only one place for them. This is why query paremeters are used for the root segment, because there also can only be one at any given time.